# D7 brane profile

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, ads-cft, branes

I have a doubt about the differential equation leading to the profile of a d7 brane embedded in a 10 dimensional space. According to http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306018, equation (6), we have the asymptotic behaviour of the embedment solution. Can you comment on the way the authors arrived to that conclusion? Is there any general way of analysing the asymptotic behaviour of an EoM such as (5)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please try to make the post self-contained (e.g. include the relevant equations etc)? Here, we aim not to rely on outside sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no complication in arriving at equation (5) given equation (5).

We have:

$$
\frac{d}{d\rho}\left[\frac{\rho^3}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy_6}{d\rho}\right)^2}}\frac{dy_6}{d\rho}\right]=0.
$$
We solve this differential equation.
$$
\frac{\rho^3}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy_6}{d\rho}\right)^2}}\frac{dy_6}{d\rho}=\tilde{c}
$$
$\tilde{c}$ being a constant of integral. Squaring both sides and rearranging:

$$
\left(\frac{dy_6}{d\rho}\right)^2=\frac{\tilde{c}^2}{\rho^6-\tilde{c}^2}
$$
In the limit $\rho\to\infty$ we can neglect $\tilde{c}^2$ in the denominator and we have:

$$
\frac{dy_6}{d\rho}=\frac{\tilde{c}}{\rho^3}
$$

which we can integrate to get:

$$
y_6=m-\frac{2\tilde{c}}{\rho^2}
$$
m being another constant of integration. Redefine $-2\tilde{c}\to c$ and we get equation (6) in the paper.